# compare a string with a value in xsl tag in xsl:

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to use if in xsl to compare two values, but i want to compare a string with a value that i can access it by xsl tag. if i compare with a value(without xsl tag), it works. I mean:

```
<xsl:if test="$prev4 &gt;0">
```

but the fallowing has error:

```
<xsl:if test="$prev4 &gt;0<xsl:value-of select="@wholeCount"/>">
```

I don't know how to do this comparing. Can you please help me? thank you

Comment: user1597122, In XSLT 1.0 you can just use: `<xsl:if test="$prev4 > @wholeCount">` . In XSLT 2.0: `<xsl:if test="$prev4 gt xs:integer(@wholeCount)">` . You *don't* need to put the second argument in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an XSL variable as below:

```
 <xsl:variable name="counter" select="@wholeCount"/>
```

Then use the variable in comparison:

```
  <xsl:if test="$prev4 &gt; $counter">
```

Answer (score 3):

**Actually, it isn't necessary at all to place the second argument in a variable -- so the currently accepted answer teaches you wrong**.

Just use (both in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:if test="$prev4 > @wholecounter">
```

**Here is a complete example**:

**This simple XML document**:

```
<t wholecounter="1"/>
```

**when processed with the following transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="prev4" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:if test="$prev4 > @wholecounter">
      $prev4 is greater than @wholecounter
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  $prev4 is greater than @wholecounter
```